# how is char able to store an address?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I'm a beginner and I absolutely can't figure out how some string returns a pointer to its location in memory?

```
char* str = "okay"
```

why is it a pointer? After all, we don't even use `new`

Comment: BTW: `char* str = "okay"` is not legal in modern c++ (since the 2011 standard).

Comment: Also a string in c++ is `std::string` you are studying c-strings

Comment: just an example

Comment: A pointer refers to a location in your computer's memory.  Your program can have objects in memory without ever using `new`.

Comment: Because it is an array of chars. For more details better to read one of those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: The variable `str` is a pointer because you used `*` in `char *`.  If you want a single character use `char` without the `'*'`.  If you want text (more than one character), use `std::string`.

Answer (score 4):

> how is char able to store an address

It doesn't, it's a pointer *to* a `char`.

> how some string returns a pointer to its location

String literals are (generally) constant character arrays stored in a read-only section in memory that's mapped to a section in your executable. More details are OS-specific, but what's important is that string literals decay into a pointer to their 1st character, just like any other array.

> After all, we don't even use `new`

`new` and `malloc()` return pointers, sure, but they're not the only source of pointers. As you see in your code, string literals are a source of pointers as well, and nothing stops you from writing stuff like `char *p = (char *)0x800;` if you want, which is something you see often in kernel or real-mode programming.